# Is there any faster way to copy paste in Excel?

Tags: excel, formula

I have a list of data that I need to keep copy paste with the same data
I found is stupid that I keep copy paste due to I have 10000 over data inside my excel sheet.

Is there any faster way to allow me copy paste the same data in few minutes?

Below will be my data:

```
       A            B         C                 D      E       F      G
1    17449   2JW3-1512-P2   NPJW3A3177      0.111   3.149   0.024   0.034
2                                           0129    3.100   0.026   0.033
3                                           0130    3.200   0.023   0.025
4                                           0131    3.159   0.024   0.015
5    17580    2JW3-1511-P2  NPJW3A3177      7129    3.160   0.025   0.015
6                                           7130    3.140   0.025   0.014
7                                           7180    3.214   0.023   0.011
```

Is there any faster way that I want A2:C4 will fill in with the data same as A1:C1
while A6:C7 will fill in with data same A5:C5

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this. First move your data down one row to give you a empty first row. Then in `H2` put this formula:

```
=IF(A2="",H1,A2)
```

Now copy that across two columns and down to the bottom of your data.

Then your spreadsheet would look like this:

```
+---+-------+--------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------------+------------+
|   |   A   |      B       |     C      |   D   |   E   |   F   |   G   |   H   |      I       |     J      |
+---+-------+--------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------------+------------+
| 1 |       |              |            |       |       |       |       |       |              |            |
| 2 | 17449 | 2JW3-1512-P2 | NPJW3A3177 | 0.111 | 3.149 | 0.024 | 0.034 | 17449 | 2JW3-1512-P2 | NPJW3A3177 |
| 3 |       |              |            | 129   | 3.1   | 0.026 | 0.033 | 17449 | 2JW3-1512-P2 | NPJW3A3177 |
| 4 |       |              |            | 130   | 3.2   | 0.023 | 0.025 | 17449 | 2JW3-1512-P2 | NPJW3A3177 |
| 5 |       |              |            | 131   | 3.159 | 0.024 | 0.015 | 17449 | 2JW3-1512-P2 | NPJW3A3177 |
| 6 | 17580 | 2JW3-1511-P2 | NPJW3A3177 | 7129  | 3.16  | 0.025 | 0.015 | 17580 | 2JW3-1511-P2 | NPJW3A3177 |
| 7 |       |              |            | 7130  | 3.14  | 0.025 | 0.014 | 17580 | 2JW3-1511-P2 | NPJW3A3177 |
| 8 |       |              |            | 7180  | 3.214 | 0.023 | 0.011 | 17580 | 2JW3-1511-P2 | NPJW3A3177 |
+---+-------+--------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------------+------------+
```

You can now copy columns `H2:J8` over to `A2:C8` (or as far down as you need to go) and in one copy/paste you're done. Make sure you paste values, not formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Select A:C, HOME, Editing,- Find & Select, Go To Special..., Blanks, OK

<kbd>=</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

then copy down the last entries in ColumnsA:C to suit.

Answer (score -2):

Just select `A1:C1` together, and then drag the bottom right cross (fill handle) down to fill in `A2:C4`.

Similarily, select `A5:C5` together and fill `A6:C7` with data by dragging the cross down again.

---

Alternatively, if you have large range of cells to fill, you can also use the Fill Button in the menu. For example, if you wanted to fill `A5:C5` downwards for say 100 rows, you can do this:

1. Put in the inital data for `A5:C5`.
2. In the Excel Name Box, type in `A5:C105` and press enter (the Name Box is located left of the formula bar). `A5:C105` should now all be selected.
3. On the Home Ribbon tab > Editing Group > Fill, Select the "Down" option.
   [image: Fill Button]

Now each row in `A5:C105` should be filled exactly with whatever was in `A5:C5`.